# Android Studio generates thousands of cache files in gradle/caches/ and in wrapper files over 100MB so cannot be pushed to GitHub

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, version-control

I was playing around Android Studio and have the issue, that when I first download project from VCS (GitHub) it then downloads all gradle files locally. The problem is, that it is very uncomfortable when there are thousands of files from /gradle/caches (not from .gradle it's added to .gitignore).
The problem is that it is difficult to find what files I need to commit and push among thouse thousands:
[image]

Moreover, some files downloaded /gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.0.2-bin/p1l23p1lpas/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip is 112 mb, which makes it unavailable to push to GitHub because of the 100 MB limit.
Whenever I tried to remove these cache files or zip of gradle it would download again on the restart of Android Studio. Anyone knows how could it be sorted out?

MacOS + Android Studio 2020.3.1 Patch 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, somehow I managed to set gradle project files source and therefore Android Studio was downloading everything.
To fix it go to:
File > Project Structure > SDK Location > Gradle settings > 'Gradle user home'

Remove anything that is in 'Gradle user home'.